# Emmet not working in WebStorm in .php files

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

I just started using WebStorm. Emmet is working perfectly with `.html` files, but not with `.php` files. Any fix for that?

Problem: writing `.container` + clicking on <kbd>Tab</kbd> should give `<div class="container"></div>`, but it's not doing that in PHP files. In HTML files it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WebStorm, `.php` files are simple text files highlighted using textmate bundles; HTML language is not injected there, so advanced HTML features do not work.

As a workaround, you can try modifying **Zen HTML** live templates context in **Settings | Editor | Live Templates** by appending **Other** to it, like:

[image]

but this has to be done for each template separately